# Make the edit toolbar show edit, add, remove, and sort

Tags: c#, 2sxc

2SXC 8.8.0
DNN 7.4.2
C# Razor template

I want to limit the edit controls on my content items to be edit, add, remove, and sort (sort being the drag and drop interface where I can also change the list header values).

I've figured out I can use @Edit.Toolbar(Content, actions: "edit,add,remove") but I tried adding 'sort' to the list but it just shows an empty blue icon - I obviously don't have the correct name for it. How can I add the 'sort' icon?

Comment: I found this page: https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/Razor-Edit.Toolbar

Comment: But when I use 'sort' it shows a blank blue square and 'undefined'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is on the wiki-page you've found:

"This grouping is currently static and cannot be changed. Because of this, just using actions: "develop" won't show anything, because it's hidden till the more button was clicked a few times. So if you want any advanced buttons, for now you'll also need to supply the more as well, like actions: "develop,more". This will be optimized some day."

Your code must look like:

@Edit.Toolbar(Content, actions: "edit,add,remove,more,sort")

Comment: Thanks for finding this. Unfortunately, the code you provided doesn't work - it yields the exact same results with a blank blue button that says 'undefined' when I hover over it. Perhaps this is a bug in 2SXC 8.8.0?

Comment: You are right, the correct code is:                                
@Edit.Toolbar(Content, actions:"edit,add,remove,instance-list")
instance-list is the new name for sort and you don't need more anymore...